# Match characters at start of string, ignore strings in html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

A little help required please...

I have a regular expression that matches characters at the start of a string as follows:

If I have a set of strings like so:

```
Ray Fox 
Foster Joe
Finding Forrester
```

**REGEX**

```
/\bfo[^\b]*?\b/gi
```

This will match 'FO' in Fox, Foster, and Forrester as expected:

However, I am faced with an issue where if the set of strings are wrapped in html tags like so;-

```html
<span class="fontColor1">Ray Fox</span>
<span class="fontColor2">Foster Joe</span>
<span class="fontColor3">Finding Forrester</span>
```

This will match 'FO' in fontColor* as well.

I'm fairly green with Regular expressions, I need a little help updating the query so that it only searches values between HTML tags where HTML tags exist, but still works correctly if HTML tags do not exist.

Comment: Have you considered [using an HTML Parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve; why are you using a regex on those strings. Do you want to hide spans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a html parser and extract pure text, and match that.

```
var root;

try {
    root = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("").body;
}
catch(e) {
    root = document.createElement("body");
}

root.innerHTML = '<span class="fontColor1">Ray Fox</span>\
            <span class="fontColor2">Foster Joe</span>\
            <span class="fontColor3">Finding Forrester</span>';

//If you are using jQuery
var text = $(root).text();

//Proceed as normal with the text variable
```

If you are not using jQuery, you can replace `$(root).text()` with `findText(root)`, where `findText`:

```
function findText(root) {
    var ret = "",
        nodes = root.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
            ret += nodes[i].nodeValue;
        } else if (nodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
            ret += findText(nodes[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I took the option of ensuring I am only passing strings (without html tags) to the relevant function, I think I finally get it now, the issue with using regex to work with HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<.*?span.*?>(.*?)<\s?\/.*?span.*?>
```

And where do you have text where html tags don't exist?  That makes no sense.

EDIT:

This solution will not match nested tags, but as the question is written, that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: This would match more than one open-close tag pair at a time because of the (.*?) in the middle. This is illustrative of the difficulties of trying to deal with HTML just with regexes. As mentioned above, just use an HTML parser and use regexes on the text content.

Comment: You are correct.  I've seen a regex that does exactly this.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Nope, I found the regex I was looking for, and it doesn't solve the issue of nested tags.  But, looking at the question, that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: @RyanLynch i want to find a text in innerhtml and wants that it will skip the tags at the time of finding suppose <i> or<font> or <span > tag comes in between of tag to how to skip those and match the string